# How to implement two-factor authentication in asp net core 6.0 with identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am new to ASP.NET Core 6.0 Identity two-factor authentication. The latest identity framework added several Razor pages, which include `EnableAuthenticator.cshtml`, `TwoFactorAuthentication.cshtml` and `LoginWith2fa.cshtml`.

I am not sure how to use them in the register and login process flows. I am following the method described in this link.

https://www.meziantou.net/implementing-two-factor-authentication-in-an-asp-net-core-application.htm

As per the link I have downloaded and included `qrcode.js` in the `wwwroot/js` folder and added the following code at the end of the `EnableAuthenticator.cshtml` file.

```cshtml
@section Scripts {
  <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
  <script src="~/lib/qrcode/qrcode.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrCode"),
        {
            text: "@Html.Raw(Model.AuthenticatorUri)",
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        });
  </script>
}
```

Whenever someone registers to the site with email/password, in the `AspNetUsers` table, I am setting `TwoFactorEnabled = true`. While login, I am not sure whether to redirect to `LoginWith2fa` page or to  `EnableAuthenticator` page.

The following is my code on the login page:

```csharp
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                
            string url = $"{stringeGrantsURL}{"?UserToken="}{jwtToken}";

            return Redirect(url);
        }

        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, 
                   RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    return Page();
}
```

With the current code the user is sent to the `LoginWith2fa` page which asks to enter an authenticator code, which is not available.

Instead, if I direct the user to the `EnableAuthenticator.cshtml` page, it simply redirects to the `Login.cshtml` page. I tried to Google the issue, but most of the samples pertain to ASP.NET Core 5.0 which uses MVC identity and not the .NET Core 6.0 which uses Razor pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the exact solution I was looking for at this site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRdAndBlLd8&t=83s

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever someone registers to the site with email/password, in the
> AspNetUsers table, I am setting TwoFactorEnabled = true

In fact,you shouldn't simply set the `TwoFactorenabled` column to true in db,you have to follow the steps in this page to configure authenticator app first:

[image]

> if I direct the user to the EnableAuthenticator.cshtml page, it simply
> redirects to the Login.cshtml page.

You could check the [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3fcd84946cf63794a3913a79d47f5143ea0f30ae/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions.cs#L32) of Identity

```
 public void PostConfigure(string name, RazorPagesOptions options)
        {
            name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder(IdentityUIDefaultAreaName, "/Account/Manage");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage(IdentityUIDefaultAreaName, "/Account/Logout");
            var convention = new IdentityPageModelConvention<TUser>();
            options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention(
                IdentityUIDefaultAreaName,
                "/",
                pam => convention.Apply(pam));
            options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention(
                IdentityUIDefaultAreaName,
                "/Account/Manage",
                pam => pam.Filters.Add(new ExternalLoginsPageFilter<TUser>()));
        }
```

It added gobal Authorize Attribute to Manage folder,If you haven't login(with 2FA)  successfully, it would redirect you to login page

You should follow the flow:

1,Log in with email/password

2,enable 2FA Authentication follow the guidence

3,when you login with 2FA,enter the code you get from Microsoft Authenticator

Comment: Do you know if LoginWith2fa should be set with an [AllowAnonymous] filter? I noticed when I scaffolded this and other Account pages, while majority of the Page Models have the [AllowAnonymous] filter, this was one of them that did not. When I set a global authentication fitler to make sure a user is authenticated by default, of course the the LoginWith2fa page cannot be accessed unless I add the [AllowAnonymous] filter. I see there is a check to see if the user went through the login page first.. but wonder why by default this didn't come with an {AllowAnonymous] filter when scaffolded.